Cómo puedo eliminar un commit de github antiguo que fue pusheado al repositorio remoto pero sin cambiar nada del proyecto final
Necesito eliminar un commit de github antiguo que fue pusheado al repositorio remoto pero sin cambiar nada del proyecto final. Esto porque me di cuenta que como estoy aprendiendo compartí información sensible en un par de commits que no debería haber subido (API key). Necesito ayuda con el paso a paso de los comandos por favor. Es importante que no se altere el proyecto tal y como está.
Probé usando git rebase para eliminar los dos commits que quería, pero se empezó a alterar archivos que no quería modificar y lo revertí con git rebase --abort

La integridad criptografica de los commits en Git hace que no puedas modificar ningún commit antiguo sin tener alguna consecuencias en los siguientes. Lo que es posible hacer, es volver el proyecto al commit en cuestión, modificar o eliminar el archivo en conflicto y reconstruir/simular luego toda la historia de cambios que siguen a ese commit, el resultado final debiera ser lo que estás buscando con la salvedad que el hash de cada commit posterior al del conflicto va a ser distinto, eso puede traer algún problema si el hash se usa en otras herramientas, enlaces, o simplemente lo has compartido.
Está documentado en Github un procedimiento probado para hacer esto: "Removing sensitive data from a repository", es bastante simple usando las herramientas que mencionan bfg-repo-cleaner o git.repo-filter. Yo tuve experencia con bfg-repo-cleaner y siguiendo los pasos mencionados en el documento el resultado fue el esperado.
Comentarios adicionales:

Fundamental seguir particularmente la instrucciones para actualizar el repo remoto
Lo del cambio de los "hash" ya lo comenté
Invalidar la password o la información sensible que se ha subido (siempre que se pueda)
Al ser git un sistema distribuido deberías asegurarte que todas las copias del proyecto vuelvan a ser clonadas localmente


nota aparte.. si compartiste una API key, ya fuiste es publica.. lo que hagas para removerla de GIT es inservible si ademas no caducas dicha pass y avisas en todos lados que fue expuesta...
